# Using Supremum to prove $|x+y| \leq |x|+|y|$ vs. my proof

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-writing, absolute-value

I saw postings on MathStackExchange for this but I need to prove it using the 
definition of Supremum. I proved it the way I see it. I do not see the Supremum way. I would appreciate help.

$ \forall x, y \ \ \ \epsilon \ \Re$

Prove
 $\lvert x+y\rvert \leq  \lvert x\rvert + \lvert y\rvert$

My Proof:

$$ 1) \,(x+y)^2 = x^2 + 2xy + y^2 $$

Using the fact* that:
$${\sqrt {x^2}}  =  \lvert x\rvert$$
$$x^2 =  \lvert x\rvert ^2$$

We have$$2) \,x^2 + 2xy + y^2 = \lvert x\rvert ^2 + 2xy + \lvert y\rvert ^2  $$

And using:
$$xy  \leq  \lvert xy\rvert$$

We have 
$$3) \,x^2 + 2xy + y^2 = \lvert x\rvert ^2 + 2xy + \lvert y\rvert ^2  \leq \lvert x\rvert ^2 + 2\lvert xy\rvert + \lvert y\rvert ^2 $$

Again using the fact*

$$\lvert x+y \rvert^2 =(x+y)^2$$
We have
$$4) \,\lvert x+y \rvert ^2\leq \lvert x\rvert ^2 + 2\lvert xy\rvert + \lvert y\rvert ^2 $$

$$5) \,\lvert x+y \rvert^2 \leq (\lvert x\rvert + \lvert y\rvert  )^2$$

$$6) \,\lvert x+y \rvert\leq \lvert x\rvert + \lvert y\rvert$$

Thanks in Advance for your help!

Comment: Very nice. More briefly,  $|x+y|^2=$ $(x+y)^2=$ $=x^2+2xy+y^2\leq $ $x^2+|2xy|+y^2=$ $=x^2+2|x|\cdot |y|+y^2=$ $|x|^2+2|x|\cdot |y|+|y|^2=$ $(|x|+|y|)^2.$

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct. But of course one could avoid considering quadratic expressions.  In any case nobody in his right mind would use a supremum argument to prove the triangle inequality. Note that this inequality already holds in ${\mathbb Z}$, which is centuries away from the idea of supremum.